# Change chart to log chart C#

Tags: c#, charts, scale, interactive

Is it possible to change the scale of the y-axis on a chart to be logarithmic? I want to do it by clicking on a button even after the points have been plotted.

Here is the code for my scatterplot. The `X` value is the length of an array of numbers I am using in a bubble sort algorithm. The `Y` value comes from a stopwatch used to time how long the method takes to sort.

```
type = "bubble";                
chart1.Series[type].Points.AddXY(dataArray.Length, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: You should provide some code. As it stands no-one has any idea what tools and or controls you are using for your plotting - it's a bit of an open ended question as is.

Comment: @Übercoder I updated the question

Comment: Try this: `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLogarithmic = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Axis.IsLogarithmic sets a flag which indicates whether the axis is logarithmic. Zeros or negative data values are not allowed on logarithmic charts.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.islogarithmic(v=vs.110).aspx

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLogarithmic = true;